# Marshalling "uint8_t" get zero contents

Tags: c#

I got contents 0 in array from marshalling uint8_t. I could not forund error.

C++:

```
typedef struct {

    uint8_t tst[64];

} Info_t;
```

C#:

```
public struct Info_t
        {


            public byte[] tst;


            public Info_t(bool initializeByteArrays)
            {

                tst=new byte[64];

            }
        }
[DllImport(@"D.dll",  EntryPoint = "connect", ExactSpelling = false)]
public static extern ushort connect(Info_t test);


Info_t dd = new MainForm.Info_t(true);
ushort res = connect(dd);
```

OUTPUT:

dd.tst[0]=0
...
dd.tst[63]=0

Comment: How is the `connect` function declared?

Comment: Don't you need to tell the marshaler how long your array is?

Comment: @Flydog57  yes i tell long of array with

Info_t dd = new MainForm.Info_t(true);

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski c++ connect function just returns Info_t struct

Comment: my question is that how to marshall c++ uint8_t array in struct to csharp i could not managed to find it yet :/

Comment: Use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]`. The marshaller can't see that you instantiate the array on your ctor.

Comment: There is more than one problem.  The biggest is certainly that the struct is passed by value, the native code can never update it.  Make sure this function works in C++ before you try to use it from C#.

Comment: @canton7 I use Use [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)] now error is {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my issue;

The second way is to use the "out" keyword. So when you use it , it will auto return the value form the unmanagerd memory.

[Solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b39f077-3db3-48c8-8dce-b642f41a0bfa/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-on-c-dll-calling-from-c?forum=Vsexpressvcs)